# A Multi-Index Construction for Intraday TimeSeries (10 min price data)

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, pandas, multi-index

I have a file with intraday prices every ten minutes. [0:41] times in a day. Each date is repeated 42 times. The multi-index below should "collapse" the repeated dates into one for all times.

- There are 62,035 rows x 3 columns: `[date, time, price]`.
- I would like write a function to get the difference of the ten minute prices, restricting differences to each unique date.

In other words,  09:30 is the first time of each day and 16:20 is the last: I **cannot** overlap differences between days of price from 16:20 - 09:30. The differences should start as 09:40 - 09:30 and end as 16:20 - 16:10 for each unique date in the dataframe.

Here is my attempt. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
def diffSeries(rounded,data):

'''This function accepts a column called rounded from 'data'
 The 2nd input 'data' is a dataframe 
'''

df=rounded.shift(1)
idf=data.set_index(['date', 'time'])  
data['diff']=['000']

  for i in range(0,length(rounded)):

    for day in idf.index.levels[0]:


      for time in idf.index.levels[1]:

        if idf.index.levels[1]!=1620:

          data['diff']=rounded[i]-df[i]

        else:
          day+=1
          time+=2

data[['date','time','price','II','diff']].to_csv('final.csv')

return data['diff']
```

Then I call:

```
data=read_csv('file.csv')

rounded=roundSeries(data['price'],5) 

diffSeries(rounded,data)
```

On the traceback - I get an `Assertion Error`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupby and then apply to achieve what you want:

```
diffs = data.groupby(lambda idx: idx[0]).apply(lambda row: row - row.shift(1))
```

For a full example, suppose you create a test data set for 14 Nov to 16 Nov:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randn
from datetime import time

# Create date range with 10 minute intervals, and filter out irrelevant times
times = pd.bdate_range(start=pd.datetime(2012,11,14,0,0,0),end=pd.datetime(2012,11,17,0,0,0), freq='10T')
filtered_times = [x for x in times if x.time() >= time(9,30) and x.time() <= time(16,20)]
prices = randn(len(filtered_times))

# Create MultiIndex and data frame matching the format of your CSV
arrays = [[x.date() for x in filtered_times]
         ,[x.time() for x in filtered_times]]
tuples = zip(*arrays)

m_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['date', 'time'])
data = pd.DataFrame({'prices': prices}, index=m_index)
```

You should get a DataFrame a bit like this:

```
                       prices
date       time              
2012-11-14 09:30:00  0.696054
           09:40:00 -1.263852
           09:50:00  0.196662
           10:00:00 -0.942375
           10:10:00  1.915207
```

As mentioned above, you can then get the differences by grouping by the first index and then subtracting the previous row for each row:

```
diffs = data.groupby(lambda idx: idx[0]).apply(lambda row: row - row.shift(1))
```

Which gives you something like:

```
                       prices
date       time              
2012-11-14 09:30:00       NaN
           09:40:00 -1.959906
           09:50:00  1.460514
           10:00:00 -1.139036
           10:10:00  2.857582
```

Since you are grouping by the date, the function is not applied for 16:20 - 09:30.

You might want to consider using a TimeSeries instead of a DataFrame, because it will give you far greater flexibility with this kind of data. Supposing you have already loaded your DataFrame from the CSV file, you can easily convert it into a TimeSeries and perform a similar function to get the differences:

```
dt_index = pd.DatetimeIndex([datetime.combine(i[0],i[1]) for i in data.index])
# or dt_index = pd.DatetimeIndex([datetime.combine(i.date,i.time) for i in data.index]) 
# if you don't have an multi-level index on data yet
ts = pd.Series(data.prices.values, dt_index)
diffs = ts.groupby(lambda idx: idx.date()).apply(lambda row: row - row.shift(1))
```

However, you would now have access to the built-in time series functions such as resampling. See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html) for more about time series in pandas.

Answer (score 0):

@MattiJohn's construction gives a filtered list of length 86,772--when run over 1/3/2007-8/30/2012 for 42 times (10 minute intervals). Observe the data cleaning issues.

Here the data of prices coming from the csv is length: 62,034. 
Hence, simply importing from the .csv, as follows, is problematic:

```
filtered_times = [x for x in times if x.time() >= time(9,30) and x.time() <= time(16,20)]
DF=pd.read_csv('MR10min.csv')
prices = DF.price
 # I.E. rather than the generic: prices = randn(len(filtered_times))  above.
```

The fact that the real data falls short of the length it "should be" means there are **data cleaning issues**. Often we do not have the full times as bdate_time will generate **(half days in the market, etc, holidays)**.

Your solution is elegant. But I am not sure how to overcome the mismatch between the actual data and the a priori, prescribed dataframe.

Your second TimesSeries suggestion seems to still require construction of a datetime index similar to the first one. For example, if I were use the following two lines to get the actual data of interest:

```
DF=pd.read_csv('MR10min.csv')
data=pd.DF.set_index(['date','time'])


dt_index = pd.DatetimeIndex([datetime.combine(i[0],i[1]) for i in data.index])
```

It will generate a:

```
TypeError: combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not str
```

**How does one make a bdate_time array completely informed by the actual data available?**

Thank you to (@MattiJohn) and to anyone with interest in continuing this discussion.